# Security issues with oauth2-redirect and nip.io

Tags: azure, ssl, oauth-2.0, dns

I am developing a small demo API for my organization. I use Azure AD for authentication for the API (and the OpenAPI docs). Everything works perfectly in my local development environment and I don't have the hassle of SSL since the oauth2-redirect is localhost. I am now ready to make my demo accesible inside my organization's network. However, Azure App Registration mandates that a oauth2-redirect link has to be https (or localhost which is why it works perfectly for me). I can understand why, but I am eager to demo my API and so, if at all possible, I would like to avoid the hassle of setting up a reverse-proxy, configuring TLS etc. So my question is - if I use https://10.x.x.x.nip.io/oauth2-redirect what are the security implications of this? I fear they are major unfortunately. I guess nip.io could sniff my authorization if they wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly an answer, since it doesn't discuss the security implications of nip.io. However, if TLS is an issue for a demo it is automatically configured for an Azure App Service. For small demos it is therefore very convenient to deploy as an Azure App Service especially if you protect it behind a private link.